# What's byebug's version of pry's whereami?

Tags: ruby, byebug, binding.pry

In Ruby, we have a gem called `byebug` and a gem called `pry`.

In `pry`, you can type `whereami` to see where you are, when you are in a `binding.pry` session.

How do you do the same thing in `byebug`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar to `whereami` in byebug is `list` https://fleeblewidget.co.uk/2014/05/byebug-cheatsheet/

you can also type `help` when in a byebug session to get the list of commands